# Change mysql db location when installed with homebrew

Tags: mysql, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

I just installed mysql via homebrew and I wanted to change the location where mysql stores the databases.  All the stuff I've found so far online have paths that I don't understand and don't exist on my machine (OSX 10.8).

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have MySQL running a simple `ps ax | grep mysql` will yeld the process path.

Otherwise search your fs for mysqld it will take some time but will get the job done:

```
sudo find / -type f -name "mysqld"
```

A `find / | grep mysql` will print every file containing mysql in its name.

Use MySQLWorkbench, it has a nice GUI which lets you configure INNODBs data path and will also help you managing your instances.

Otherwise edit `/etc/my.cnf` (or create it if you don't have any) insert a `[mysqld]` section and set `innodb_data_home_dir = /path/to/where/you/moved/your/data`

```
[mysqld]
innodb_data_home_dir = /path/to/where/you/moved/your/data
```

Comment: ps ax | grep mysql helped me find my datadir which is apparently /usr/local/var/mysql.  If I move this folder to another location, how do I tell mysql where the new location is?

Answer (score 3):

When started via homebrew services:

1. Stop the server: brew services stop mysql@5.6
2. Modify the plist file for your installed version, for example: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/5.6.43/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.6.plist
3. Look for the --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql key and set the value to the place you want to store your databases.
4. Copy over files from /usr/local/var/mysql to your new location.
5. Restart the server: brew services start mysql@5.6

Comment: Thank you, @BrettBond! 

This worked for me for  mysql installed with brew, version 8.0.16 on macOS Mojave v. 10.14.4